# Es cardinality not giving exact count

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I want to fetch exact db counts in my elastic search by using cardinality function, but it's not working as it is giving count precisely.
My piece of code using in ES,

```
GET patient_claim/_search?size=0
{"aggs" : {"type_count" : { "cardinality" : {"field" : "patientReference"}}}}
```

Can somebody tell how to fetch exact db counts in ES.

Comment: Cardinality aggregation is approximate [by design](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate), so I am pessimistic that one can get exact number of different values of a field. Did you try any other aggregation? May you provide an example set of documents and expected outcome, just to be sure that I understood you well?

Answer (score 1):

As @Nikolay Vasiliev stated in the comments, this aggregation will return only an approximate value. However you can trade memory against accuracy by increasing the default value of the setting precision_threshold from 3000 to 40000 (100%)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but i don't want any precision to be included as i have data more than 40000. Is there any way to get the exact count?

Comment: The 40000 is not the number of documents/data the precision is applied to. This is the threshold of your desired precision and 40000 is the maximum. You can see it as 100%.

Comment: @zeba have you had any success with my answer and comments?

Comment: I am able to fetch exact count through painless scripting.

Comment: For future seekers, this [article](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7) includes an explanation of how to script a solution. Getting accurate deduplicated counts requires a Set to deduplicate values and as a result can be memory intensive, which is likely why Elastic Search doesn't provide an out of the box solution for this problem.